# Canon EDSDK Java set library path

Tags: java, edsdk

I have the following problem:

I want to run a photobooth application in Java (Windows) using the Canon EDSDK.

But when I open the connection to the camera, I get this error: 
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'EDSDK/Dll/EDSDK.dll'**

Is there a way to manually set the path to my EDSDK-library?

I'm using the edsdk4j-library: https://github.com/kritzikratzi/edsdk4j/

Here's the code:

```
    static CanonCamera dslr;
    static boolean connected = false;

    public static void init() {
        dslr = new CanonCamera();    //This line throws the error
        dslr.openSession();
        connected=true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you [install the EDSDK](https://github.com/kritzikratzi/edsdk4j/#applying-with-canon-for-esdk-software-development-kit-access) as the project suggests?

Otherwise I suggest enabling the debug logs to see where the projects looks for the DLL:

```
// In your main, before the SDK setup
edsdk.utils.DLL_Setup.debug = true;
```

( See [here](https://github.com/kritzikratzi/edsdk4j/blob/b43dd9c774afb098292cedf6be75c5a3acee0ec4/src/main/java/edsdk/utils/DLL_Setup.java#L124) )

Comment: jna.library.path: C:\Users\Dominik\Documents\PhotOS\lib

Comment: But the EDSDK-folder is located inside this folder, thus this error shouldn't be thrown.

Comment: You could try to descend the stack with the debugger and see exactly where it fails?

Comment: It fails when it's trying to load the native library